Retrieving the access token of the user who created the new user
I am currently working on a Spring Boot application integrated with Keycloak for authentication and authorization. I have an event listener in my Keycloak that listens for user creation events in Keycloak. When a new user is created in Keycloak, this event listener triggers a call to an external API to store the new user information in my application.
I need help with the following:

How can I retrieve the access token of the currently logged-in user (the user who created the new user in Keycloak) within the event listener?

How can I use the retrieved access token to authenticate a call to an external API within the event listener?


I created a custom event listener that will trigger when user creation is done in Keycloak and it will call the external API, but I am getting access of the user who created the user.

Were you able to figure something out?
